# cdata-section-elements - for same elements in different XPath cannot be ignored

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a particular schema in which element with same names with different Xpath are defined multiple times in the target schema. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
    <Record> // First record
        <Name>test</Name>
        <id>id2</id>
        <Rollno>Rollno3</Rollno>
    </Record>
    <Record1> // Second Record
        <Name>Name6</Name>
        <id>id7</id>
        <Rollno>Rollno8</Rollno>
     </Record>
</Root>
```

The above is the XML which is being used and Name is the element into consideration.

Since I am using the `cdata-section-elements="Name"` in the XSL for transformation.

Although I only want the output of the `Name` element of `Record1` to be in CDATA not that of `Record/Name`. As of now for the all the name elements the output is coming in CDATA. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Why do you *need* the output to be CDATA at all? Generating output with CDATA makes it more difficult to do downstream parsing and processing.

Comment: Well that is a particular requirement that for one the elements Cdata is required and not for the other .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cdata-section-elements parameter in the serializer doesn't give you this level of control.

Your requirement is quite difficult to achieve, and therefore I think it's quite reasonable for Mads Hansen to ask why you really need this. CDATA is often used inappropriately.

One way to achieve the requirement might be to use a different element name in the result tree for the elements you want to be CDATA, and then post-process the serializer output to change the element names back.

Another way to do it would be to generate the CDATA markup using character maps (output special characters, e.g. from the Unicode user-defined character range, to indicate start and end of CDATA sections, and then map these characters to CDATA start and end tags).

Comment: Thank You Mike , although I posted the same in the Saxonica Support as well :) , thanks for the reply